# No HDMI video output from GeForce GT 330M - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, drivers, hdmi, monitor

I have a Dell Vostro with an Nvidia graphics card. Although the VGA output works fine, when I connect up a monitor on the HDMI output, Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) recognises it, but the screen is blank (no signal). Here's the output from

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 == 
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation 
model    : GT216M [GeForce GT 330M] 
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000A29sv00001028sd0000044Fbc03sc00i00 
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin 
driver   : nvidia-304-updates - distro non-free 
driver   : nvidia-331 - distro non-free recommended 
driver   : nvidia-331-updates - distro non-free 
driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free
```

I've tried the proprietary drivers, but none have solved the problem, and the 331 driver caused a hang at boot time when the GUI tried to start.
Is there a recommended driver I should be using with this card? Anyone else had this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: I thought I was alone in the dark... ;)

Comment: @abelinux I've actually given up on this. The machine has a hybrid graphics card, which just does not want to work properly with Ubuntu. I tried everything to get it working, but no joy. :-(

Comment: Uff... I feel somewhat relieved... I thought I was the only person in the universe that couldn't make this work =P    Just FYI, (barely) same hardware (Vostro 3700, Intel HD4000 + Nvidia GT330M in hybrid config, HDMI out), same results (no image ever out of HDMI port, even the new screen is recognized, in Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, ElementaryOS; only works on Windows when hybrid "switch" is set to use NVidia graphics card)

Comment: Score one for Windows on this occasion ;-)